# Cron job runs task during cron and redirects

Tags: 7, cron

When I run a cron job, it sometimes will redirect to the background task status page and then redirect to the messages page. However, cron does not get marked as run. If I do it again, right away, it will then be marked as run and it gives me the standard cron info.

I am using a standard cron job, not when the page loads.

Comment: There could be something in the queue still running, have you given it time (by navigating around the site for a little while) to make sure that all queued items are completed?

Comment: I'm not using poor man's cron. I'm calling the external cron url using curl. Or what queue? Shouldn't everything run without redirecting?

Comment: Invoking cron shouldn't result in a redirect, everything should take place in cron.php. Look through your codebase for implementations of hook_cron, might help you narrow down the offender

Comment: The Drupal queue, you can configure things to run on cron but instead of all running at the same time it can be a queued action so the cron wouldn't actually be complete until that queue is complete running also, that means that like 25 items (if it configured for that) run everyone time Drupal loads a page, this helps to stop things like php timeouts or slow loading times. Are there any messages showing on the messages page?

Comment: Ok, I see. No, actually it redirects to the page with the progress bar and then redirects to the message types page or something like that.